# how get child id by using 5 parentids jumps in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have many records. Root node's parent ID is null and from leaf node if I start to traverse through the Parent IDs, I will reach to root node after some 6-10 jumps. So I know the ID of current node(leaf or intermediate). Is there any way to find the depth of that child efficiently?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please explain with some example data and show expected result

Comment: If I want to get child id 1110 By using parent id 1.so first I have to select 1 - 1112  and 1112-1111  and then 1111- 1110.

Answer (score 1):

Here I am just leveling every rows (Recursive CTE) by parent - child relationship like top parents are level 1, their first children are level 2 and thereafter 3, 4 going on. Now from there you could just seek any rows with conditioning Parent and Level.

```
;WITH INITIAL AS
(

    SELECT * FROM          --You will change this dummy data by your table.
    (VALUES                --You will change this dummy data by your table.
        ('P1', NULL),      --You will change this dummy data by your table.
        ('C1', 'P1'),      --You will change this dummy data by your table.
        ('C2', 'P1'),      --You will change this dummy data by your table.
        ('C11', 'C1'),     --You will change this dummy data by your table.
        ('P2', NULL)       --You will change this dummy data by your table.
    ) TC(ID, ParentID)     --You will change this dummy data by your table.

), FINAL AS 
(
    -- Anchor
    SELECT ID,
    ParentID,
    LEVEL = 1
    FROM   INITIAL

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursion
    SELECT D.ID,
    D.ParentID,
    LEVEL = LEVEL + 1
    FROM INITIAL D
    INNER JOIN FINAL RC
    ON RC.ID = D.ParentID
), MyLastTable AS
(
    SELECT 
    TOP 1 WITH TIES 
    * 
    FROM FINAL
    ORDER  BY Row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LEVEL DESC) 
) SELECT * FROM MyLastTable 
WHERE LEVEL = 2 AND ParentID = 'P1' -- Change here with your condition
```

Change INITIAL table values by your own data and MyTable where condition at last of query as your requirements.

Comment: Your solution seems fine, but you should avoid using code only answers. Please add some explanations in text to make your answer upvote worthy.

Comment: @MD.Ziaulhaq did you checked ??

Comment: If not worked then tell me what you want after this and if worked then tag me right answer :)...